# I want to make a wireworld move, however it shows me a error

Tags: haskell, parse-error

I'm asked to make a wireworld move. So i have written the following codes,(all of the function in the code is somehow defined in other modules, so, dont worry about that XD, feel free to ask me if u want to have a look at those "predefined funcs") however when i run it on terminal, it shows a error, here is the code:

```
module Transitions.For_List_2D (
   transition_world -- :: List_2D Cell -> List_2D Cell
) where

import Data.Cell (Cell (Head, Tail, Conductor, Empty))
import Data.Coordinates
import Data.List_2D

transition_world :: List_2D Cell -> List_2D Cell
transition_world world = case world of
    (Head,(x,y)):rest-> (Tail,(x,y)): transition_world rest
    (Tail,(x,y)):rest -> (Conductor, (x, y)): transition_world rest
    (Empty, (x, y)):rest ->(Empty, (x, y)): transition_world rest
    (Conductor, (x, y)):rest
      | element_occurrence==1 || element_occurrence==2 = (Head, (x, y)): transitio
        n_world    rest
      | otherwise = (Conductor, (x, y)): transition_world rest
    [] -> []
```

however, when i ran it on terminal by "./'name of the hs file'", it show the following error:

```
For_List_2D.hs:23:56: parse error on input '='
```

Im totally confused by this error
Thank you in advance for anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines

```
  | element_occurrence==1 || element_occurrence==2 = (Head, (x, y)): transition_world    rest
  | otherwise = (Conductor, (x, y)): transition_world rest
```

should be

```
  | element_occurrence==1 || element_occurrence==2 -> (Head, (x, y)): transition_world    rest
  | otherwise -> (Conductor, (x, y)): transition_world rest
```

We use `=` in equations (e.g. function definitions) and `->` in case expressions.